# Stylus: how to create a CSS variable with a Mixin interpolation

Tags: css, stylus

How can a Stylus Mixin interpolate for both sides of the definition of a variable, such as:

```
--MyVariable: MyVariable
```

In the compiled CSS, `--MyVariable` should remain as the variable name, whereas the second variable should be the numerical value computed for this Stylus variable defined elsewhere.

I will have many such pairs of a CSS variable and a Stylus variable. Now, even though I could just manually write them down in the Stylus file, I would like to have a Mixin that allows me to create them by writing the shared part of the names just once as the Mixin's single argument, such as:

```
VariablePair(MyVariable-1) // --MyVariable-1: MyVariable-1
VariablePair(MyVariable-2) // --MyVariable-2: MyVariable-2
VariablePair(MyVariable-3) // --MyVariable-3: MyVariable-3
```

I tried:

```
VariablePair(VariableName)
  --{VariableName}: VariableName

VariablePair(MyVariable)
```

It didn't parse.

I realized that `MyVariable` without `''` would come as an actual value that couldn't be affixed to `--`. But, adding `''` to it as `VariablePair('MyVariable')` would result in the right side of the definition itself becoming a string instead of the Stylus variable for computation.

I tried the different combinations of the presence/lack of the brackets and `''` and `$` as well as concatenations, but none of them seem to work. `'--' + VariableName + ': ' + VariableName` (with/without the brackets/`$`) isn't working, it either doesn't parse or does parse but without creating a line in the compiled CSS.

Is there a solution to this?

Answer (score 3):

`unquote` [works for this](https://stylus-lang.com/try.html#?code=VariablePair(name%2C%20val)%0A%20%20%7Bunquote(%27--%27%20%2B%20name)%7D%3A%20val%0A%0A.selector%0A%20%20VariablePair(%27fontcolor%27%2C%20%27red%27)%0A%20%20color%3A%20var(--fontcolor)):

```
VariablePair(name, val)
  {unquote('--' + name)}: val

.selector
  VariablePair('fontcolor', red)
  color: var(--fontcolor)
```

will output

```css
.selector {
  --fontcolor: #f00;
  color: var(--fontcolor);
}
```